# Can XDocument.Load() and XDocument.Parse() be combined into one?

Tags: .net, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I have `XDocument.Load()` which loads XML from a file and `XDocument.Parse()` which loads XML from a string, 
is there any way to combine them and load from a file or string dynamically?

Comment: Please rephrase your question. It is not clear what you want

Comment: Well, you could write code to choose which method to use depending on where the XML is coming from.  If you're asking if there's a framework method to call `Load` or `Parse` at runtime depending on the type, then no, there's not.

Comment: @Jehof - I don't think the `linq-to-xml` tag is necessarily applicable here, as the question doesn't have anything (yet) to do with LINQ, even though the `XDocument` is part of linq-to-xml.

Comment: @Tim then remove it if you think so

Comment: @Tim can i achieve that out of box

Comment: @akashhh - Not that I know of.  As I said, there is nothing in the framework that does that for you.  You can however write code to make the decision on which one to use - See Sam's answer for one way.  There are others.

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that you mean XDocument.PARSE() and not XDocument.PRASE(), I believe the below function should help you in this regard. 
We just check to see if the file exists first before loading it, if it doesn't exist then it should be an xml string. in both cases we cover ourselves with a try catch and return null.

To use the below I would double check that the return is not null before continuing.

```
if(LoadXml(xmlFile) == null)
{
    //enter code for fail to load, will continue if correct.
}
```

The Function:

```
     private XDocument LoadXml(string xmlFile)
     {
         //initialise a new XDocument
         XDocument doc = new XDocument();

         //check to see if xmlFile exists as a file in the OS.
         if (File.Exists(xmlFile))
         {
             //try XDocument.load()
             try
             {
                 doc = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);
             }
             catch (Exception)
             {
                 //if the load did not succeed then return null
                 return null;
             }
         }
         else
         {
             //if it is not a file then try parsing the string.
             try
             {
                 doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlFile);
             }
             catch (Exception)
             {
                 //if the parse failed (i.e. the string is not an xml format) then make doc = null
                 return null;
             }
         }
         //return doc
         return doc;
     }
```

Comment: Why use a `Stream` to load `XDocument`?  If the file exists, simply use the `XDocument.Load(string)` overload.

Comment: A very good point Tim. In this case we don't need the xmlFile for anything else. I'll amend it now